# cornflakes-linter (flake8 in VSCode) reports issues in Python files in ~/.vscode/.... directories (VSCode extensions)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8

After a couple of minutes of editing a Python project in VS Code, cornflakes-linter starts showing flake8 issues for VS Code extensions in addition to issues from the code in the project. Excluding `~/.vscode/` directory or `*.pyi` files in `.flake8` file does NOT seem to have any impact.

Any ideas what I am missing?

[image: flake8 problems list]

Comment: Are these files opened during editing? Could you please provide us with the content of the settings file "settings.json" and the specific issues in the file displayed on the terminal?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I managed to get the errors to go away by adding the following python.linting.ignorePatterns setting to my settings.json file: 

`".vscode/*.py",  "**/site-packages/**/*.py", "**/AppData/Local/**", "**/.venv/**/*.py",     "**/.vscode/extensions/**/*.py", "**/.vscode/extensions/**/*.pyi"`